# problem with using the citation style "unsrt"

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper using documentclass 'article' and using jabref for bibliography. While I was using unsrt as the citation style its giving me the following problem....

for example, i wrote multiple author name like..

```
Díez-Pascual, A. M. \& Ashrafi, B. \& Naffakh, M. \& González-Domínguez , J. M. 
\& Johnston, A. \& Simard, B. and Martínez, M. T. \& Gómez-Fatou, M. A.
```

but the output is coming like...

```
B. & Naffakh M. & González-Domínguez J. M. & Johnston A. & Simard B. Díez-Pascual,
A. M. & Ashrafi and M. A. Martínez, M. T. & Gómez-Fatou
```

any kind of help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you describe has nothing to do with the `unsrt` bibliography style -- it would appear with any other bibliography style as well. In BibTeX, the separator between names of a multi-authored piece is `and`, not `\&`. Moreover, BibTeX might choke on accented characters such as `á`, `í`, and `ó` -- replace them with `{\'a}`, `{\'i}`, and `{\'o}`, respectively. Try setting up the name field as

```
name = {D{\'i}ez-Pascual, A. M. and Ashrafi, B. and Naffakh, M. and
       Gonz{\'a}lez-Dom{\'i}nguez , J. M. and Johnston, A. and Simard, B. 
       and Mart{\'i}nez, M. T. and G{\'o}mez-Fatou, M. A.},
```

and you should be in business.

You mention that you use `jabref`: check the settings to ensure that when you output a file in `.bib` format, the software knows (i) to use `and` as the separator between names in a name field and (ii) to use "constructed" accented characters rather than their direct representations.

Comment: I am sorry to say that its not working for me. let me just give u a short example...input:Nielsen, L. E. and Landel, R. F. and out put is:R. F. Nielsen, L. E. and Landel

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (minimum working example) that reproduces the problem behavior you're encountering. Without such information, it's nearly impossible to diagnose -- let alone fix -- the problem properly.